# How to turn off caching in Mojolicious::Renderer

Tags: perl, caching, mojolicious

my_app.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

my $route = Mojolicious::Routes::Route->new;

sub foo($c) {
    $c->stash(one => 23);
    $c->render(template => 'magic', two => 24);
}

my $renderer = app->renderer;
# $renderer->cache(undef); <- ?
# Route to templates files
$renderer->paths(['/var/www/site/templates/']);

any '/foo' => \&foo;

app->start;
```

magic.html.ep:

```
The magic numbers are <%= $one %> and <%= $two %>!
```

Then run the application:

```
$ morbo my_app.pl
```

It works, but when I change the template it doesn't change the output because the template is cached:

```
Rendering template "magic.html.ep"
Rendering cached template "magic.html.ep"
```

How can I turn it off during development? I tried `$renderer->cache(undef);`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps all you want is to add your template dir to the list of watched dirs using morbos -w switch? https://docs.mojolicious.org/morbo

Comment: `$renderer->cache->max_keys(0)` disables caching. Or use [this plugin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::Renderer::WithoutCache)

Comment: I am the author of Mojolicious::Plugin::Renderer::WithoutCache, which @clamp pointed out. I knew this would come in handy some day for someone. Yay.